# Using xdg-open for accessing network with normal explorer

Tags: networking, terminal, open-files, protocols

I'm working with small network and I want to start network explorer from a terminal. When I tried to type `xdg-open network:///server` it opened google chrome and did nothing. I also tried to type `smb://server` but it hasn't helped me. I really need to run it from terminal. Does anybody know how can I do it?

Comment: I don't think that xdg-open currently will mount smb automatically. https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50401

Comment: And what about network?

Comment: Are you literally using "network://"? I don't see that as an option. I see the term "network" used as a general term for things like smb:/// and magnet:/// etc.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: See my answer, I still think if you want to open a samba server you have to use smb://something. You'll need to incorporate the domain name etc. into the smb:/// command in order for it to work. LMK and I can add these details to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think I see what you're attempting to do. On my system (Redhat Fedora 14) using GNOME desktop I have a choice of **Network** in Nautilus.

[image: ss of nautilus network:///]

It's also accessible under the **Places** pulldown.

[image: ss of GNOME menu]

[image: network under places]

Any of the following commands open the **Network** Browser for me.

```
% xdg-open 'Network:'
% xdg-open 'network:'
```

**NOTE:** Either of the above with any number of trailing slashes appears to work too!

```
% xdg-open 'Network:/'
% xdg-open 'network://'
% xdg-open 'Network:///'
```

#### Tips for mounting SMB shares

`xdg-open` doesn't appear to be able to mount shares that aren't mounted. For example, here's a SMB share that hasn't been explicitly mounted yet via `Nautilus`:

```
% xdg-open 'smb://MYDOM;sam@bart/sam'
gvfs-open: smb://MYDOM;sam@bart/sam/: error opening location: The specified location is not mounted
```

However if I manually mount it in `Nautilus` it then can be accessed using `xdg-open`:

[image: ss of smb mounted in nautilus]

```
% xdg-open 'smb://MYDOM;sam@bart/sam'
```

If you'd like to avoid the step of making the SMB mount manually you could use the **GNOME** applet, `Gigolo`, which will automatically mount any shares you specify. See this page for more info on the [Gigolo website](http://www.uvena.de/gigolo/) and also this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGw6VTOyU8g).

#### EDIT #1

In discussing this with OP he's using `Mint 14 (Nadia)`, which includes a fork of `Nautilus` from `GNOME 2 & 3`. These forks are called `MATE` and `Nemo` respectively.

There is a known issue with these forks that I mentioned to OP in this [launchpad issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1001902). Specifically, there was a [patch](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/123382163/xdg-open.patch) that supposedly fixed the issue with `xdg-open`.

Comment: It must be in system settings. I'm using LinuxMint and it not works. I've also tried to install nautilus, but it still not works. Do I need to change some config files?

Comment: I'm using 14 nadia

Comment: I've saved it to `xdg` and used `patch < xdg`. `can't find file to patch at input line 3`, so I typed path manually and the path was applied. It still opens it in browser.

Comment: Can you put your `xdg-open` file somewhere such as pastebin so I can see it? http://pastebin.com/. Post the link back here.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/jpp28jkX